# Rails 4 Ajax: Delete nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I'm trying to delete a "collection" on a project page. When I click the delete link I get this error:

> No route matches [GET] "/collections/87"

Where is my mistake?

---

**My files:**

Routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
  resources :collections, :except => [:update, :destroy]
end

resources :collections, :only => [:update, :destroy]
```

collection.rb

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  ...
  validates :project, presence: true
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections, reject_if: proc() { | attrs | attrs[ 'title' ] .blank? }, allow_destroy: true

end
```

collections_controller.rb

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  respond_to :html, :js

  def destroy
    @project = @collection.project_id
    @collection.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @project }
      format.js # render collections/destroy.js.erb
    end

  end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_with(@projects)
  end

  def show
    @collection = Collection.new
    @collections = @project.collections.order("title ASC")
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_with(@project)
  end

...
```

/projects/show.html.erb

```
<% @collections.each do |collection| %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Collection', collection, method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your collection controller which don't get the collection in question.

The change could be :

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  respond_to :html, :js

  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

    @project.collections.find(params[:id]).delete

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @project }
      format.js # render collections/destroy.js.erb
    end

  end
```

Comment: Sry for the late answer @knotito! I get this output
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/collections/89")`